# How do you move a repo when using Git Kraken?

Tags: git, macos, gitkraken

I am getting started with GitKraken, and can't seem to find a simple answer to this question. When I move a folder GitKraken can no longer see it. Is there a way to change the file path that it is looking for so that it can find a moved folder? Ideally within the GUI itself.

I can always make a new repo in the new location and then move the files there, but then I lose the commit history. I am also using Mac OS, if it matters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Move the repository folder and then just **"Open"->"Open a Repository"** from the new path.